# how to set page number for different section in word by poi

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, footer, page-numbering

My document has three parts: cover, contents and text. I want to set different page number for each section. The cover does not need page numbers. The contents page numbers are in Rome numerals, and the pages in the main body are in Greek numbers. Can it be realized with POI？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Apache poi` is - until now - only abel creating three types of header / footers: [HeaderFooterType](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/wp/usermodel/HeaderFooterType.html)`.DEFAULT`, `.EVEN` and `.First`.

So for fulfilling your requirement we need using the underlaying low level objects. And we need cheating a little bit to be able creating different footers.

We need two different footers. One for your section 2 (contents) and one for your section 3 (text). But both must be of type `DEFAULT`. Since this is not possible using `apache poi` until now, we are first creating two different footers of different types (`FIRST` and `DEFAULT`) for the whole document. Then we change the `FIRST` footer  to `DEFAULT` and move it to be footer reference for section 2.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.wp.usermodel.HeaderFooterType;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTDocument1;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTBody;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSectPr;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTHdrFtrRef;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STHdrFtr;

public class CreateWordMultipleSectionPageNumbering {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument();

  //create first footer for section 2 - first created as first footer for the document
  XWPFFooter footer = document.createFooter(HeaderFooterType.FIRST); 
  //making it HeaderFooterType.FIRST first to be able creating one more footer later
  //will changing this later to HeaderFooterType.DEFAULT

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = footer.getParagraphArray(0);
  if (paragraph == null) paragraph = footer.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Page ");
  paragraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple().setInstr("PAGE \\* ROMAN MERGEFORMAT");
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText(" of ");
  paragraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple().setInstr("NUMPAGES \\* ROMAN MERGEFORMAT");

  //create second footer for section 3 == last section in document
  footer = document.createFooter(HeaderFooterType.DEFAULT);

  paragraph = footer.getParagraphArray(0);
  if (paragraph == null) paragraph = footer.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Page ");
  paragraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple().setInstr("PAGE \\* ARABIC MERGEFORMAT");
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText(" of ");
  paragraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple().setInstr("NUMPAGES \\* ARABIC MERGEFORMAT");

  //create document content.

  //section 1
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Cover");

  //paragraph with section setting for section above
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  CTSectPr ctSectPr = paragraph.getCTP().addNewPPr().addNewSectPr();

  //section 2
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Contents");

  //paragraph with section setting for section above
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  CTSectPr ctSectPrSect2 = paragraph.getCTP().addNewPPr().addNewSectPr(); //we need this later

  //section 3 
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Text");

  //section setting for section above == last section in document
  CTDocument1 ctDocument = document.getDocument();
  CTBody ctBody = ctDocument.getBody();
  CTSectPr ctSectPrLastSect = ctBody.getSectPr(); //there must be a SectPr already because of the footer settings above

  //get footer reference of first footer and move this to be footer reference for section 2
  CTHdrFtrRef ctHdrFtrRef = ctSectPrLastSect.getFooterReferenceArray(0);
  ctHdrFtrRef.setType(STHdrFtr.DEFAULT); //change this from STHdrFtr.FIRST to STHdrFtr.DEFAULT
  CTHdrFtrRef[] ctHdrFtrRefs = new CTHdrFtrRef[]{ctHdrFtrRef};
  ctSectPrSect2.setFooterReferenceArray(ctHdrFtrRefs);
  ctSectPrLastSect.removeFooterReference(0);

  //unset "there is a title page" for the whole document because we have a section for the title (cover)
  ctSectPrLastSect.unsetTitlePg();

  document.write(new FileOutputStream("CreateWordMultipleSectionPageNumbering.docx"));

 }
}
```

Reference for used low level objects: http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/.

---

The above code shows the principle. If the need is to fulfilling further requirements then one should know that a `*.docx` file is simply a `ZIP` archive which one can unzip and have a look into it. So one can using `Word` for creating a `*.docx`  file which fulfils the requirements, then unzipping it and look at `/word/document.xml`.

For example:
"How to set roman numerals start with I II and arabic numerals start with 1,2  again?"

If in `Word` [create a Word document that uses different page numbering formats](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/326536/how-to-create-a-word-document-that-uses-different-page-numbering-forma) . Then in `/word/document.xml` you will find something like:

```
...
 <w:sectPr>
  ...
  <w:pgNumType w:start="1"/>
  ...
 </w:sectPr>
...
```

So we need a `PgNumType` element in the `XML` for this.

Complete example again:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.wp.usermodel.HeaderFooterType;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTDocument1;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTBody;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPPr;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSectPr;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTHdrFtrRef;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STHdrFtr;

public class CreateWordMultipleSectionPageNumbering {

 //default section setting for page size and page borders
 //measurement unit = twips (twentieth of an inch point) = 1 inch = 1440 twips
 private static String defaultSectPr = 
   "<w:sectPr xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\">"
  +"<w:pgSz w:w=\"12240\" w:h=\"15840\"/>" //A4
  +"<w:pgMar w:top=\"1417\" w:right=\"1417\" w:bottom=\"1134\" w:left=\"1417\""
  +" w:header=\"720\" w:footer=\"720\" w:gutter=\"0\"/>"
  +"<w:cols w:space=\"720\"/>"
  +"</w:sectPr>"; 

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  CTSectPr ctSectPrDefault = (CTPPr.Factory.parse(defaultSectPr)).getSectPr();

  XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument();

  //set the default section setting for page size and page borders 
  CTDocument1 ctDocument = document.getDocument();
  CTBody ctBody = ctDocument.getBody();
  ctBody.setSectPr(ctSectPrDefault);

  //create first footer for section 2 - first created as first footer for the document
  XWPFFooter footer = document.createFooter(HeaderFooterType.FIRST); 
  //making it HeaderFooterType.FIRST first to be able creating one more footer later
  //will changing this later to HeaderFooterType.DEFAULT

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = footer.getParagraphArray(0);
  if (paragraph == null) paragraph = footer.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Page ");
  paragraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple().setInstr("PAGE \\* ROMAN MERGEFORMAT");
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText(" of ");
  //paragraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple().setInstr("NUMPAGES \\* ROMAN MERGEFORMAT");
  paragraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple().setInstr("SECTIONPAGES \\* ROMAN MERGEFORMAT");

  //create second footer for section 3 == last section in document
  footer = document.createFooter(HeaderFooterType.DEFAULT);

  paragraph = footer.getParagraphArray(0);
  if (paragraph == null) paragraph = footer.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Page ");
  paragraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple().setInstr("PAGE \\* ARABIC MERGEFORMAT");
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText(" of ");
  //paragraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple().setInstr("NUMPAGES \\* ARABIC MERGEFORMAT");
  paragraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple().setInstr("SECTIONPAGES \\* ARABIC MERGEFORMAT");

  //create document content.

  //section 1
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Cover");

  //paragraph with section setting for section above
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph.getCTP().addNewPPr().setSectPr(ctSectPrDefault);

  //section 2
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Contents");
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum semit dolor ...");
  run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE); 
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  //paragraph with section setting for section above
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph.getCTP().addNewPPr().setSectPr(ctSectPrDefault);  
  CTSectPr ctSectPrSect2 = paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getSectPr(); //we need this later
  //set this page numbering starting with 1 again
  ctSectPrSect2.addNewPgNumType().setStart(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(1));

  //section 3 
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Text");
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum semit dolor ...");
  run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE); 
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  //section setting for section above == last section in document
  CTSectPr ctSectPrLastSect = ctBody.getSectPr(); 
  //there must be a SectPr already because of the default and footer settings above
  //set this page numbering starting with 1 again
  ctSectPrLastSect.addNewPgNumType().setStart(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(1));

  //get footer reference of first footer and move this to be footer reference for section 2
  CTHdrFtrRef ctHdrFtrRef = ctSectPrLastSect.getFooterReferenceArray(0);
  ctHdrFtrRef.setType(STHdrFtr.DEFAULT); //change this from STHdrFtr.FIRST to STHdrFtr.DEFAULT
  CTHdrFtrRef[] ctHdrFtrRefs = new CTHdrFtrRef[]{ctHdrFtrRef};
  ctSectPrSect2.setFooterReferenceArray(ctHdrFtrRefs);
  ctSectPrLastSect.removeFooterReference(0);

  //unset "there is a title page" for the whole document because we have a section for the title (cover)
  ctSectPrLastSect.unsetTitlePg();

  document.write(new FileOutputStream("CreateWordMultipleSectionPageNumbering.docx"));

 }
}
```

This also uses `SECTIONPAGES` field in `Word` insteand of `NUMPAGES` to numbering only the pages in single section istead of the whole document pages.

Also it uses default section settings for page size and page borders in each section. This is more compatible with different word processing applications which can read `*.docx`  files.

Comment: Thanks! The answer is very useful to me, but there is another problem.How to set Rome  number start with I II  and Greek number start with 1,2 ?

Comment: @bill: See my supplements.